# density function of $Z=\sqrt{(X^2+Y^2)}$ when $f_{xy}(x,y)$ is given

Tags: density-function

A point is randomly chosen from a disk of radius R centred at the origin so that each point in the disk is equally likely than X and Y are jointly continuous with joint density given by

> $$f_{xy}(x,y)=
>    \Biggr\{
>     \begin{array}{lr}
>       \frac{1}{\pi R^2}&  x^2+y^2<R^2  \\
>      0& \text{otherwise}
>       \end{array}$$ 
>   Find density function of $Z=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$

I am trying to do it like this first find $F_{Z}(z) \hspace{4pt}which\hspace{4pt} is \hspace{4pt}\frac{x^2+y^2}{z^2}$ then differentiate  it with respect to $z$ to get $f_Z(z)$.

Comment: Maybe try to find $f_x(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dy$ and then using it?

Comment: not useful already did that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $0 < Z=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2} < R$. Thus we have $P(Z\leq z)=1$ for $z\geq R$ and $P(Z \leq z)=0$ for $z < 0$.

Now consider $0 \leq z < R$. We have $P(Z \leq z)=P(X^2+Y^2 \leq z^2)=\int_{x^2+y^2 \leq z^2}\frac{1}{\pi R^2}dA=\frac{z^2}{R^2}$.

Thus, the pdf of $Z$ is $f_{Z}(z)=\frac{d}{dz}F_{Z}(z)=\frac{2z}{R^2}I_{(0<z<R)}$.